# Adding layout dynamically to ScrollView android

Tags: android, layout

I want to add xml layout dynamically to scrollview in my application, but it is showing an error.

This is my code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myContent1);
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View vv = vi.inflate(R.layout.headerone, null); 
    ll.addView(vv);//, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ll.getLayoutParams().width, ll.getLayoutParams().height));

    View vv2 = vi.inflate(R.layout.headertwo, null); 
    ll.addView(vv2);//, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ll.getLayoutParams().width, ll.getLayoutParams().height));

    View vv3 = vi.inflate(R.layout.headerone, null); 
    ll.addView(vv3);
```

"headerone.xml" and "headertwo.xml" are my two xml layout files.

Comment: 1. What error is it showing? 2. Please format your code properly using CTRL+K.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(19121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19121): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.test.list/com.test.list.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Bi
nary XML file line #2: Error inflating class scrollview

Comment: it is working fine with only LinearLayout

Answer (score -1):

Probably

A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects.

But we would need to see the XML to be sure.